# New to Python 3 - Trying to get results to print in table

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and am having issues getting information to print in a table once 'n' or 'N'is entered. The code is below. I am probably missing something simple but have not been able to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the result. As you can see, even after N is printed, it continues to ask for speed input:

Enter the speed in MPH.50
Enter the time travelled in hours.3
Do you have another calculation to enter? (Enter y for yes or N for no: )y
Enter the speed in MPH.60
Enter the time travelled in hours.4
Do you have another calculation to enter? (Enter y for yes or N for no: )y
Enter the speed in MPH.75
Enter the time travelled in hours.3
Do you have another calculation to enter? (Enter y for yes or N for no: )n
Enter the speed in MPH.

'   # This program will calculate the distance a vehicle has travelled
    # in miles using speed (mph) and the number of hours travelled.

```
# Create a variable to represent the maxium travel time in hours.
max_travel = 9
min_travel = 1
# Create a variable to represent the maximum speed.
max_speed = 120
# Create a variable to represent the minimum speed.
min_speed = 1
#Define a variable to represent continuation of the program
another = ["y", "Y"]
# Create a variable for saved results to be printed in table
results = []

# main module
def main():

    # Get the speed in MPH.
    speed = int(input('Enter the speed in MPH.'))

    # Validate that the speed entered is not out of range.
    while speed > max_speed or speed < min_speed:
      if speed > max_speed:
            print('ERROR: the speed entered must be a lower number between 1   and 120.')
            speed = int(input('Enter a lower speed in MPH.'))

        if speed < min_speed:
            print('ERROR: the speed entered must be a higher number between 1 and 120.')
            speed = int(input('Enter a higher speed in MPH.'))

    # Ask user to input travel time in hours
    travel_time = int(input('Enter the time travelled in hours.'))

    # Validate that the time travelled is within the range of 1 to 9 hours.
    while travel_time > max_travel or travel_time < min_travel:
        if travel_time > max_travel:
            print('ERROR: the time must be a lower number between 1 and 9.')
            travel_time = int(input('Enter a different time travelled in hours.'))

    # Validate that the time travelled is within the range of 1 to 9 hours.
        if travel_time < min_travel:
            print('ERROR: the time must be a higher number between 1 and 9.')
            travel_time = int(input('Enter a different time travelled in hours.'))

    # This will cause the loop, with the exception of the first loop,
    # to depend on a 'y' or 'Y' entry to enter any additional entries. 
    first = False 

    # Calculate again?
    another = input('Do you have another calculation to enter? ' + \
            '(Enter y for yes or N for no: )')

    # This loop will continue until something other
    # than 'y' or 'Y' is entered when prompted.
    while another == 'y' or 'Y':
        main()

    # Calculations saved for table
    input_tuple =speed, travel_time

    # Print the column headings in a table.
    # Print the time travelled and the
    # result of the distance calculation 
    print()
    print('Hours\t\tDistance')
    print('---------------------')

    # Print saved entries and calculations in table
    if another !='y' or 'Y':
        for input_tuple in results:

    # Calculate the distance travelled
    distance = speed * travel_time
    print("'%s'\t\t'%s'" %(travel_time, distance))

# Call the main function.
def main():
"""
"""'
```

Comment: Indent with 4 spaces only. No more. No less. Do not use tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Beware that the code comes with many indentation errors. Having said that you should at least correct

```
while another == 'y' or 'Y'
```

to

```
while another == 'y' or another == 'Y'
```

indeed `or 'Y'` always evaluates to `True`

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still trying to catch all of the little nuances that can throw everything off. I imagine that gets better with practice!